# 仮想DOMについての疑問

Tags: javascript, reactjs

jQueryとかでDOMを操作すると、reactjs側で保持している仮想DOMと差が生じると思います。そうすると、レンダリング時に差分が反映され、jQueryとかで行った操作が消えてしまうような気がしてなりません。
大丈夫なんでしょうか？

Answer (score 6):

reactjsは外部でDOMが操作されたことを知り得ないため、安全ではありません。

仮想DOMとの矛盾が生じた場合、予期しない動作を引き起こす可能性がありますので、外部からDOMを操作する場合は、仮想DOMの挙動を意識する必要があります。

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3218#issuecomment-75513815

> Mutation of DOM node attributes/properties is safe (but should be  avoided). Mutation of the DOM node hierarchy for anything but insertion of nodes into empty leaves is disaster waiting to happen.
>
> （訳注：React外からの）DOMノードの属性・プロパティの変更は安全です（避けるべきですが）。空の末端へのノードの挿入を除いて、あらゆるDOMノードの階層構造の変更は、いつ大惨事を引き起こしてもおかしくありません。